# Cant display null values in phpmyadmin, any explanation on what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

so I have a problem with my database, I've run into a problem that seems stupid, Im trying to run a command that should work, but wont return any data,
Here is a screenshot of my table "invites"
[my table "invites"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlcmw.png)

As you can see there is data in there, Mainly note the "used" column, On all of them it is NULL,

Im trying to run this command:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*)
FROM invites
WHERE used = ''
GROUP BY country
```

In theory this should return how many country's with a count of how many of them have used = NULL,

but this doesn't return anything, I've tried to pinpoint where it is going wrong, It seems whenever I include WHERE used='' it wont return anything, It seems no value in my column "used" is equal to NULL.

Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone have an idea on why It wont return anything

Comment: `WHERE used is null`. `''` is a zero length string.

Comment: Thank you, It worked.